# daisy UI custom theme not working after importing

Tags: daisyui

I had imported daisy UI plugins. But still converts itself to **dark mode** how to fix that problem? I wanted my theme in light mode without using **data-theme** light in the html attribute

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In tailwind.config.js set themes to false. Example:
`module.exports = { plugins: [require('daisyui')], daisyui: { themes: false } };`

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to ***tailwind.config.js***, the light theme will be applied. If you want to use different themes then you can [visit here](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/)

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["light"],
  },
};
```